# How do I get a 'sound scheme' in Ubuntu (or Debian)

Tags: sound, system, scheme

On Windows I had lots of custom sounds for events like opening programs, minimizing and maximizing, critical stops etc. Unfortunately I haven't found any way to have something like this on my Ubuntu and Debian (GNOME) distros. I've only been able to code an event for a logon sound but nothing else. Anyone know how to? It's pretty boring having no system sounds.

Answer (score 1):

[GNOME-Look](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/316/order/latest) has a few system sound schemes that you can download and add to your system. Generally, these sounds are placed under `/usr/share/sounds/`, but you will need to use gsettings or dconf-editor to fully apply the theme.

If you do not have dconf-editor, you should download it via `sudo apt install dconf-editor`.

You will need to get to the following area in dconf-editor: `org > gnome > desktop > sound` (also known as `org.gnome.desktop.sound`). From here, you can change the theme name (you will need to look into the theme file or folder name to see what the name of the scheme is) and enable additional sounds.

Comment: Hmm I don't seem to have 'sound' in the org > gnome > desktop path in dconf-editor

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to show up here: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/fnMglUV.png). You may have a package missing or something like that.